# When the set of official dwarf planets is expected to increase?

Tags: dwarf-planets

When the set of official dwarf planets is expected to increase or new bodies considered for inclusion?

Comment: By the way, this question was listed as "low quality" in the review queue. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "set". Do you mean the number of dwarf planets? I expect the number will increase every time a new dwarf planet is found.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in a previous answer, the official body for naming and classification of astronomical objects is the [International Astronomical Union](http://www.iau.org/), or IAU. They are the ones responsible for designating bodies as "planets," "dwarf planets," etc. The scientific community recognizes them and their decisions as "official."

The IAU meets periodically for General Assemblies to discuss general issue; [the next such meeting](http://astronomy2015.org/) is scheduled for 2015. The topics discussed may range widely, covering all sub-fields of astronomy. Unfortunately, I don't know the exact topics for discussion, and while I imagine there will be a wide range, issues relating to dwarf planets may not be covered. However, the IAU *does* meet in between these meetings to discuss a variet of topics.

That might answer your question, but if you're talking about the possible *discovery* of dwarf-planet-like bodies, I can't help you. There are probably many on-going efforts to search for small bodies within our solar system, but I don't know of any recent discoveries of possible dwarf planet candidates.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can a body be promoted to a dwarf planet without the General Assembly?

Comment: @Anixx Perhaps in the minds of some people, but the IAU is the only organization currently recognized that can give official designations.

Comment: does not IAU work between General Assemblies?

Comment: @Anixx Yes, they do. General Assemblies are only the major meetings. Edit coming.